# Hardness of a problem related to set cover

Tags: complexity-theory, np-hard, set-cover

Suppose $C_1, \ldots, C_m$ are subsets of $\{1, \ldots, n\}$. The goal is to find the smallest subcollection of $C_1, ..., C_m$ such that each element of $\{1, \ldots, n\}$ appears at least $k$ times in this subcollection.

If $k=1$, this is set cover. I would be interested to learn how to prove NP-hardness for $k=2$ and $k=3$.

Answer (score 4):

Hine: Given an instance of set cover, add $k-1$ copies of the set $\{1,\ldots,n\}$.